# Partial differentiation mixes up variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider $$ U \equiv \dot{\theta} - \theta \ ,$$

where as per usual $\dot{\theta} = \frac {d \theta}{dt}$. We then have $$ \frac {\partial U}{\partial \theta} = -1 \quad , \quad \frac {\partial U}{\partial \dot{\theta}} = 1 $$

Here is what happens if we try to compute the former partial derivative in Mathematica:

[image]

Of course, one work-around is to replace $\theta$ with say $x$ but that becomes cumbersome, especially when one has a lengthy and convoluted expression.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

EDIT: What I want to achieve is that Mathematica recognizes the two different involved quantities as two fundamentally different variables. Say we had $U \equiv \stackrel{lol}{\theta} - \theta$. Then

[image]

Same issue.

Answer (score 8):

You need to define `OverDot[\[Theta]]` to be the derivative of `\[Theta]` with respect to some variable `t`; otherwise there is no way for Mathematica to know the relation between `\[Theta]` and `OverDot[\[Theta]]`.

```
OverDot[\[Theta][t_]] := D[\[Theta], t];
```

Then

```
D[OverDot[\[Theta][t_]]- \[Theta], \[Theta]]
```

-1

and

```
D[OverDot[\[Theta][t_]]- \[Theta], Overdot[\[Theta][t]]
```

1.

Comment: The point is it does not necessarily have to be defined as the derivative of $\theta$. Say the expression is $\stackrel{cool}{\theta} - \theta$. The same problem arises. The point is I want Mathematica to recognize $\stackrel{cool}{\theta}$ and $\theta$ as two completely different  variables.